# Make current selection not selectable again with treenodes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, attributes, treeview, treenode

I have a menu as a treeview and what I'm trying to do is make whatever treenode the user selects not selectable again unless he goes to a different page. How would I do this in asp.net and vb?

update:

ok so far this is what I have going on in the treenode selection changed sub

```
   ViewState(10) = TreeView1.SelectedNode

    TreeView1.SelectedNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None

    If ViewState(10).valuepath <> TreeView1.SelectedNode.ValuePath Then
        TreeView1.SelectedNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select
    End If
```

im sure the experts out there know exactly why this wouldn't work though I was surprised it complied. Anyways This gives me an error though I can't think of another way to keep that selected node in

UPDATE:

```
  ViewState(10) = TreeView1.SelectedNode.DataItem

    If ViewState(10) <> TreeView1.SelectedNode.DataItem Then
        TreeView1.SelectedNode.Selected = ViewState(10)
        TreeView1.SelectedNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select
    Else
        TreeView1.SelectedNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None
    End If
```

This works for the selectaction.none which is exactly what I wanted but I'm having troubles enabling it again when the user selects another treenode.

Comment: I think this should be done using javascript, since it's a client-side situation.

Comment: i don't know javascript that well how would I structure the code for each treenode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer for anyone who needs this in the future

```
For Each n As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
        For Each a As TreeNode In n.ChildNodes
            If a.Selected = True Then
                a.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None
            Else
                a.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select
            End If
        Next
    Next
```